# Мне нужно решить данную задачу на последовательность

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Задано последовательность, элементы которой вычисляются по формуле: `(n + 1) / (3 * pow (n, 3) 2)`; n-целое число на промежутку [0;+∞). Написать программу, которая выводит номер
элемента этой последовательности, который отличается от предыдущего на ε = 0,0001.

Вот что я попитался написать:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double n, n_start=0, epsilon = 0.0001;
    int i = 0;
    n = n_start;
    do
    {
        if ((n + 1 - n_start) / (3 * pow(n, 3) + 2) == epsilon)
        {
            cout << "a" << i << " = " << n << endl;
            n = n_start / (2 * pow(n, 2));
            goto breakAll;
        }
        i++;
    } 
    while (i > 0);
breakAll:
    puts("I'm out!");
    cout << "n" << i << " = " << (n_start+1) / (3 * pow(n, 3) + 2) << endl;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: супер, результат то какой?)

Comment: @sensoid Неверный, плохой, не каллиграфичный)

Comment: @sensoid Его если что нет вообще просто пустая консоль

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну Вита-а-а-алик, ну где здесь "отличается от предыдущего на"?

```
if ((n + 1 - n_start) / (3 * pow(n, 3) + 2) == epsilon)
```

---

```
i = 1;
do
{
  if (fabs((i + 1) / (3 * pow(i, 3) + 2) - (i - 1 + 1) / (3 * pow(i - 1, 3) + 2)) <= epsilon)
  {
    cout << i << endl;
    break;
  }
  i++;
} 
while (i < 1000);
```

Comment: @Witalik, `==` быть точно не может, надо `<=`.

Comment: @Qwertiy может и да но мне и хватит ответа)

Comment: @Witalik, так в ответе и есть `<=`